# SQL query into a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Learning how to use dataframes. What am I doing wrong?

My attempt:

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd
from pandas import read_csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL
import time
import csv
import sys

Class Query(object):
  def do_something(self):
     con={'drivername':'mssql+pymssql','host': 'host-name', 'port': number, 'database': 'databasename','username':'username','password':'asdf'}

     query = """ select column1 from schema.table1 """

     df=pd.read_sql_query('parse',con,index_col=None,coerce_float=True,params=None,parse_dates=None,chunksize=None)

x=Query()
x.do_something()
```

the goal is to eventually store this df into a CSV file. Then, I'll need to run the query

```
query = """ select column2 from schema.table2 """
```

and append that column into the CSV file. Help please.

Comment: are you using python 3 or higher?

Comment: I am using Python 2.7

Comment: i am getting the error AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'cursor', but i do not see anything about defining the cursor when using pandas in the literature http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.read_sql_query.html#pandas.read_sql_query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40564254/workflow-for-adding-new-columns-from-pandas-to-sqlite-tables/40759987#40759987) this code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2
mydb = create_engine('postgresql://user@host.domain:5432/database')
df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT sections, ...''', con=mydb)
print(df)
```

Also you can use [pd.read_sql_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html) and pass it a list of columns. Looks like it's more convenient to loading tables.

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem. Still don't know how to save to CSV or append to said CSV.

```
con={'drivername':'mssql+pymssql','host': 'host-name', 'port': number,     'database': 'databasename','username':'username','password':'asdf'}
db_uri = URL(**database_dict)
engine = create_engine(db_uri)
query = """ select column1 from schema.table1 """

 df=pd.read_sql_query(parse,con,index_col=None,coerce_float=True,params=None,parse_dates=None,chunksize=None)
```

Comment: Save [to CSV](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html): pd.to_csv('path/to/file.csv')